Using infix and lift together for hstore queries in quill
(Using jdbc postgres driver and quill)
I have a library that needs to query hstore fields using the '@>' operator. Using Infix, I constructed the following:
val q = quote {
  auditDb.filter(row => infix"${row.rowData} @> 'paper_id=>${lift(paperId)}'".as[Boolean])
}

But attempting to run this query results in the 'The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.' error.
Running the same query with a hardcoded paperId works fine.
auditDb.filter(row => infix"${row.rowData} @> 'paper_id=><some number>'".as[Boolean])

The following query also works but is very slow.
auditDb.filter(row => infix"${row.rowData} -> 'paper_id'".as[String] == lift(paperId.toString()))


In the end the syntax that worked correctly and quickly was:
val field = s"paper_id=>$paperId"
val q = quote{
    auditDb.filter(row => sql"${row.rowData} @> ${lift(field)}::hstore".as[Boolean])
}

